# solving `DetachedInstanceError` with event.listens on SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a very similar problem as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704927/pyramid-sql-alchemy-detachedinstanceerror), however, even if I try to do something like

```
...
from my_app.models import Session
user = Session.merge(user)
new_foo = models.Foo(user=user)
...
```

Where I am basically getting the user model object from the request and trying to create a new `Foo` object that has a relation to the user, it fails with a `DetachedInstanceError` because (I think) that the `event.listens` I am using comes later on with a different `Session`.

My listener function looks like this:

```
@event.listens_for(mapper, 'init')
def auto_add(target, args, kwargs):
    Session.add(target)
```

And the `Session` is defined as:

```
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker())
```

If I am relying on `event.listens` to add a target to a `Session`, how could I make sure that objects like the user, which are added to a request context be handled?

The one thing that allowed me to make that work was to call `sessionmaker` with `expire_on_commit=False` but I don't think that is what I should be doing as (per the awesome SQLA docs) it:

> Another behavior of commit() is that by default it expires the state of all instances >present after the commit is complete. This is so that when the instances are next >accessed, either through attribute access or by them being present in a Query result set, > they receive the most recent state. To disable this behavior, configure sessionmaker with > `expire_on_commit=False`.

I want to have the most recent state of the user object. What are my options to take care of the `merge` in the right place?

The actual traceback (web framework specific lines trimmed) looks like this:

```
  File "/Users/alfredo/python/my_app/my_app/models/users.py", line 31, in __repr__
    return '<User %r>' % self.username
  File "/Users/alfredo/.virtualenvs/my_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.8.0b2-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 251, in __get__
    return self.impl.get(instance_state(instance), dict_)
  File "/Users/alfredo/.virtualenvs/my_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.8.0b2-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 543, in get
    value = callable_(passive)
  File "/Users/alfredo/.virtualenvs/my_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.8.0b2-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/state.py", line 376, in __call__
    self.manager.deferred_scalar_loader(self, toload)
  File "/Users/alfredo/.virtualenvs/my_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.8.0b2-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 554, in load_scalar_attributes
    (state_str(state)))
DetachedInstanceError: Instance <User at 0x10986d1d0> is not bound to a Session; attribute refresh operation cannot proceed
```

The actual method where this takes place is this one:

```
def post(self, *args, **kw):
    # Actually create one
    new_foo = Foo(user=request.context['user'], title=kw['title'], body=kw['body'])
    new_foo.flush()
    redirect('/pages/')
```

The problem above is that you see that I am fetching the `User` object from the request context, and that happened in a different `Session` (or at least, that is what I assume is happening).

EDIT: It seems that the use of `__repr__` is causing me issues, at some point during the request a string representation of the model is being called and this section of my model gets me in trouble:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return '<User %r>' % self.username
```

If I don't implement that method, all that I had before works as expected. What can I do to prevent this raising on the repr?

Comment: What is your motivation for using event to add new object into the Session? I would add new object right away after creating it. With using events executed by SQLAlalchemy you cannot guarantee when they'll be fired and what will be the value of global variable Session. BTW I would avoid relying Session in global context too.

Comment: There are a few things in your comment to debate:  I use `Session` as a global context as the docs imply [it is OK to do so](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session.html#getting-a-session): "... a top level Session configuration which can then be used throughout an application without the need to repeat the configurational arguments"

Comment: I am using the `scoped_session` helper which is meant specifically to associate a `Session` with the current thread. If this is not Ok, then I am misinterpreting [this section of the docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html?highlight=scoped%2520session#contextual-thread-local-sessions)

Comment: Ok. Now it makes more sense to me on why are you using global Session. But your code looks different from the documentation. As documentation in Session is a global class configured with some information (optionally - bind to engine). But in documentation another session object is instantiated `session=Session()` - instance of Session class to add/merge objects. Actually both ways work for me in single-threaded application - using Session.add and session.add. Please consider doing first `session=Session()` in main code and event code.

Comment: Can you explain where does it say that an `event.listens_for` does not guarantee it will be fired?

Comment: Unfortunatly I don't have such deep understanding of sqlalchemy innards yet. I'm just applying protective programming principles. But I can tell you how would I try to figure out what is going on in your app: I would log/print what object returns Session() in event handler function and right after you did `Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker())`. Also I would try to add breakpoint to the event handler and check which thread it was executed from and what is the stack trace using debugger.

Comment: I'm reading this thread and it seems like he said, you cannot guarantee *when* it will be fired, and depending on what events we're talking about, there may or may not be truth to that.  However the "init" event is pretty straightforward, anytime you instantiate a new object based on a mapped class, it's called.

Comment: But as far as your error there's not enough detail to say.   A constructor like Foo(user=user) doesn't do any kind of database/Session access, so this suggests something in your Foo constructor that's causing the issue (if that's where the stack trace, also not here, points).  Without full code that illustrates how the error happens it's not possible to say.

Comment: I added a bit more detail to what I am looking at, hope that helps.

Comment: Please check when your code does `Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker())`. As @zzzeek mentioned - it could the case that it was never executed before the new instance of Foo is created. Please note that scoped_session is Thread specific - thus it could be that the thread handling `post` request had never initiated scoped_session.

Comment: I found that the `__repr__` was causing this issue, if I remove it everything works as expected.

Comment: OK well, two things to look at.  One is, why calling `__repr__` when the Session is gone (that's what "detached" means)?  Usually this happens to me only when reporting an error after a rollback/close.   Second thing, make your `__repr__` check for the attribute inside of `__dict__` first, if not there, then don't call upon it, thus avoiding the lazyload.

Comment: I am not calling `__repr__` intentionally, it seems the (web) framework is doing a `str()` on it somewhere. I used your approach and falled back to a `<User detached instance>` string. I wish you had this as an answer so I could up-vote :)

Answer (score 0):

I saw same error when I run nosetest with sqlalchemy.
In my case, logging.getLogger('foo').debug('data %s', mydata) made this error. 'mydata' is a sqlalchemy mapped instance but not committed yet. My workaround is `logging.getLogger('foo').debug('data %s', repr(mydata))`

Can you change `__repr__` method as following in order to figure out your problem?

```
def __repr__(self):
    try:
        return '<User %r>' % self.username
    except:
        return 'I got it!'
```

Comment: If you read the comment thread, that is what I ended up doing